# How to group some object based on id?

Tags: java, split

I've got some object with their id. I wish to group objects based on id. I mean, object with the same id should be in a group. Is there any idea?

for example:

```
id Name

1 Allah

1 Mohammad

2 Ali

2 Fatemeh

2 Hassan

3 hossein

3 Mahdi

3 Reza
```

Comment: use a `java.util.Map` (key = id, value = list of names)?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have this type:

```
class Person {
    final int id;
    final String name;
    Person(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

You can then write the following:

```
List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(new Person(1, "Allah"), new Person(1, "Mohammad"), ..);
Map<Object, List<Person>> peoplePerId = 
people.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.id));
```

Or perhaps, even better:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> namesPerId = 
people.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
          p -> p.id,
          Collectors.mapping(p -> p.name, Collectors.toList())
      ));
```

A pre-Java 8 version:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> namesPerId = new HashMap<>();
for (Person person : people) {
    List<String> list = namesPerId.get(person.id);

    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        namesPerId.put(person.id, list);
    }

    list.add(person.name);
}
```

Comment: TNX for your reply. I have got a problem. I can not find.stream() methode on " Map<Object, List<Person>> peoplePerId = 
people.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.id));"
I have netbeans IDE 7.4, So do you It makes the problem?

Comment: In my example, I called `stream()` on a `List` (i.e. a `Collection`). `Map` is not a collection.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't get your code yet. Could you please tell me more about. I am confuse around stream() and collect().

Comment: @Arashm: I suggest reading the tutorials about the new Java 8 APIs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do it is using a Guava Multimap:

```
Multimaps.index(myObjects, new Function<MyObject, Integer>() {
  public Integer apply(MyObject input) {
    return input.getId(); 
  }
});
```

This will result in a multimap which has your IDs as single keys and the values as your objects.

In Java8 you can write this even simpler with a lambda expression:

```
Multimaps.index(myObjects, o -> o.getId());
```

If you cannot use Guava then you need to implement this behavior yourself as shown in the answer of Lukas Eder.

As for Guava, this is a quite popular library developed by Google which contains a ton of common utility classes, methods and advanced collection classes (such as bidirectional maps, multisets, and multimaps).

For more information, have a look at the [Guava Documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki).

Comment: Ooh, excellent, I wasn't aware of that. Would look even nicer with a lambda!

Comment: Oooh I am unaccustomed to use this library. Could you please let me know more about?

Comment: added the lambda version and link to Guava to the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are not reluctant to use a third-party library, you can use Google's Guava library. There exists a `MultiMap` that maps a key to a list of values, [see here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap). It works slightly different than  a `Map<Integer, List<Person>>`. It has some built-in features like `values()` that returns all values in all lists as a flat collection. Which variant suits better depends on what you want to do with the map.